# CSS Junk files in the css folder

Tags: theming

What are all those junk CSS files in site/files/css with names like css_ZFCUUB6IIfaVQ-erWDr0M0Na1JbxEsU-8zjQrWAtrbU.css? There are hundreds of them.

How do these get generated over time? What do they do?

Answer (score 5):

They aren't junk files, they are aggregated files are generated when you have CSS aggregation turned on. They make your page load times faster, as multiple files are aggregated into a single file, meaning less files have to be downloaded to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Yes @Jaypan is right. You need to check on admin/config/development/performance. In the *Bandwidth optimization* section there is an option for *Aggregate and compress CSS files*. Deselect that option and save, if you want to remove them.

Clear the cache and check.